# Is Clive the robot a reference to Clive Davis?

Tags: inspiration, despicable-me

In *Despicable Me 3*, the villain Balthazar Bratt, has robot sidekick named [Clive](https://despicableme.fandom.com/wiki/Clive). Clive is a fairly uncommon name, and Bratt (along with the theme of the movie) has an obsession with 80's pop culture and music.

**Is it possible that Clive is a reference to producer and record executive [Clive Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clive_Davis)?** Given all the other 80's references I thought this might be an easter egg for adult viewers

Comment: Perhaps the character's name is a reference to horror author Clive Barker, who wrote a lot of best-sellers in the 80s.

Comment: Or Clive, the camel from "Ahab the Arab". :-D

Comment: Or [Sir Clive Sinclair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clive_Sinclair) creator of the ZX80 from the 80s

Comment: My mind when to Clive Davis because Clive the Robot plays the music!

Comment: Probably Clive Burr, a drummer for Iron Maiden in the early 80s.

Comment: Clive really isn't that uncommon a name, sure it's no Dave, but there are plenty of Clives out there.

Comment: @Separatrix - Everyone's dead, Dave

Comment: @Valorum - Peterson isn’t, is he?